# Is an $R$-module equivalent to an $R[X]$-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, proof-explanation

This is probably a really simple question but I'm a little confused. I'm reading through a proof that concerns a finitely generated $R$-module $M$. The very first line is:

> Consider $M$ as an $R[X]$-module where the action of $X$ on $M$ is
>   given by [surjective function] ...

Why can we "view" the $R$-module as an $R[X]$-module? I'm confused about the correspondence.

Comment: "where the action of $X$ on $M$ is given by..."

That's exactly the reason why you can. He explicitly extends the action of $R$ to $R[X]$.

Comment: SInce $R$ is contained in $R[X]$, if you know how to multiply on a module $M$ by all elemebts of $R[X]$ then you know how to multiply by elements of $R$.

Comment: You don't even need the function to be surjective.

Comment: Oh ok, so instead of $rm\in M$ I now have $p(X)m\in M$ for every $p\in R[X]$ where $X$ is an endomorphism on $M$. But why are both "point of views" the same? How would we retrieve $R$ from $R[X]$? Or put differently why could we also say "view $M$ as an $R$-module" if we are given that $M$ is an $R[X]$-module?

Comment: @user118224: Of course if you have an $R[X]$-module, you can also view that as an $R$-module -- just forget about the nonconstant polynomials and their actions!

Comment: To retrieve the $R$-action, note that $R$ is canonically identified with a subring of $R[X]$.  Then restrict the action to this subring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Edit: This answer of mine is wrong - it is only true for $R$ commutative, and $s$ commuting with the image of $R,$ or for a non-commutative notion of what $R[x]$ means.]

The abstract approach.

In general, given any ring homomorphism $\phi:R\to S$, and any $s\in S$, there is a unique ring homomorphism: $\phi':R[X]\to S$ that is equal to $\phi$ on $R$ and with $\phi'(X)=s$.

Given any additive abelian group, $(A,+)$, the set of homomorphisms of the group, $\mathrm{End}(A),$ becomes a ring.

An $R$-module $M$ can be seen as an additive abelian group $M$ with a ring homomorphism $R\to\mathrm{End}(M)$.

In particular, then, if you have a ring $R$ and an $R$-module $M$, then given any other element of $s\in\mathrm{End}(M)$, you have a unique homomorphism $R[X]\to\mathrm{End}(M)$ that sends $X$ to $s$ and agrees with the $R$-module structure. That makes $M$ an $R[X]$-module.

Comment: why not authors or lecturers don't give this kind of perspectives, thank you

Comment: @Usernotfound rereading this answer of mine, it is also wrong. It is only really right if $R$ is an abelian ring, and then only if $s$ commutes with all the elements in the image of $R.$

Comment: of course, I directly assumed that, even if it is non commutative ring, chose an element $s\in S$ such that $s$ commutes with every $\phi(r)$

Comment: upss, you have already written, that I didnot read the last sentence properly